# Getting error on last } also somethig else

Tags: java

getting an error saying i need another while statement, i have checked the } multiple times but idk what is wrong
how do i also re run the program if user enters "y"
thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Charles_Peppers_Prog6 {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);

        // display the welcome / instructions
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("     Welcome to Computer Dice");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("You will be playing dice against the computer");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("you can only win with a Pair or a Straight");
        System.out.println("any Pair beats any Straight");
        System.out.println("any Pair beats any Junker");
        System.out.println("any Straight beats any Junker");
        System.out.println("in case of two Pairs - high Pair wins");
        System.out.println("in case of two Straights - high Straight wins");
        System.out.println("in case of a tie, you lose");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        // for the two die
        int d1;
        int d2;
        int d3;
        int d4;

        // keep track of results
        int wins = 0;
        int ties = 0;
        int loses = 0;

        // play again response
        String pa;

        do
        {
          // roll the two die
          d1 = (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
          d2 = (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
          d3 = (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
          d4 = (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

          // display the result of the dice roll
          System.out.println(" Player ");
          System.out.println("--------");
          System.out.print("  " + d1 + "  " + d2);
          System.out.print("\n\n");

          System.out.println(" Computer ");
          System.out.println("--------");
          System.out.print("  " + d3 + "  " + d4);
          System.out.print("\n\n");

          // determine if it is a win or a loss
          if ( d1 == d2 ) //Pair
          {
            if(d3 == d4) //computer pair
            {
                if(d1 > d3) //higher pair
                {
                    ++wins; 
                    System.out.println("Congrats, you win!");
                }
                if(d1 < d3) //lower pair
                {
                    ++loses;
                    System.out.println("Sorry, you lose!");
                }
                if(d1 == d3)
                {
                    ++loses;
                    System.out.println("Sorry, you lose!");
                }
            }
            else // only user pair
                {
                ++wins;
                System.out.println("Congrats, you win!");
                }
          }
          else
          {
            if ( (d1 == d2+1) || (d1 == d2-1) ) // Straight
            {
                if ( (d3 == d4+1) || (d3 == d4-1) ) //computer straight
                {
                    if((d1+d2) > (d3+d4))
                    {
                        ++wins;
                        System.out.println("Congrats, you win!");
                    }
                    if((d1+d2) < (d3+d4))
                    {
                        ++loses;
                        System.out.println("Sorry, you lose!");
                    }
                    if((d1+d2) == (d3+d4))
                    {
                        ++loses;
                        System.out.println("Sorry, you lose!");
                    }
                }
                if(d3==d4)
                {
                    ++loses;
                    System.out.println("Sorry, you lose!");
                }
                else
                {
                    ++wins;
                    System.out.println("Congrats, you win!");
                }
          }
          System.out.println();

          // play again question / answer
          do
          {
            System.out.print("Do you wish to play again [y, n] : ");
            pa = user.next();
          }
          while (!(pa.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || pa.equalsIgnoreCase("n")));

          System.out.println("\n");



        // display final results / report
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Computer Dice Results");
        System.out.println("---------------------");
        System.out.println("You played " + (wins + ties + loses) + " rounds");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Rounds won\t:" + wins);
        System.out.println("Rounds lost\t:" + loses);
        System.out.println("---------------------");
        System.out.println();

        user.close();

}
}
```

Comment: When you use your IDE to do the formatting what do you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had 4 mistakes, this is working code.

First mistake : you had wrong number of `}` at the end.

Second mistake : you did not initialize variable `pa`

Third mistake : you have missing `while` at the end of your `do` cycle

Foruth mistake : you closed input too soon.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Charles_Peppers_Prog6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);

        // display the welcome / instructions
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("     Welcome to Computer Dice");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("You will be playing dice against the computer");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("you can only win with a Pair or a Straight");
        System.out.println("any Pair beats any Straight");
        System.out.println("any Pair beats any Junker");
        System.out.println("any Straight beats any Junker");
        System.out.println("in case of two Pairs - high Pair wins");
        System.out.println("in case of two Straights - high Straight wins");
        System.out.println("in case of a tie, you lose");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        // for the two die
        int d1;
        int d2;
        int d3;
        int d4;

        // keep track of results
        int wins = 0;
        int ties = 0;
        int loses = 0;

        // play again response
        String pa = "";

        do {
            // roll the two die
            d1 = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
            d2 = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
            d3 = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
            d4 = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;

            // display the result of the dice roll
            System.out.println(" Player ");
            System.out.println("--------");
            System.out.print("  " + d1 + "  " + d2);
            System.out.print("\n\n");

            System.out.println(" Computer ");
            System.out.println("--------");
            System.out.print("  " + d3 + "  " + d4);
            System.out.print("\n\n");

            // determine if it is a win or a loss
            if (d1 == d2) //Pair
            {
                if (d3 == d4) //computer pair
                {
                    if (d1 > d3) //higher pair
                    {
                        ++wins;
                        System.out.println("Congrats, you win!");
                    }
                    if (d1 < d3) //lower pair
                    {
                        ++loses;
                        System.out.println("Sorry, you lose!");
                    }
                    if (d1 == d3) {
                        ++loses;
                        System.out.println("Sorry, you lose!");
                    }
                } else // only user pair
                {
                    ++wins;
                    System.out.println("Congrats, you win!");
                }
            } else {
                if ((d1 == d2 + 1) || (d1 == d2 - 1)) // Straight
                {
                    if ((d3 == d4 + 1) || (d3 == d4 - 1)) //computer straight
                    {
                        if ((d1 + d2) > (d3 + d4)) {
                            ++wins;
                            System.out.println("Congrats, you win!");
                        }
                        if ((d1 + d2) < (d3 + d4)) {
                            ++loses;
                            System.out.println("Sorry, you lose!");
                        }
                        if ((d1 + d2) == (d3 + d4)) {
                            ++loses;
                            System.out.println("Sorry, you lose!");
                        }
                    }
                    if (d3 == d4) {
                        ++loses;
                        System.out.println("Sorry, you lose!");
                    } else {
                        ++wins;
                        System.out.println("Congrats, you win!");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();

                // play again question / answer
                do {
                    System.out.print("Do you wish to play again [y, n] : ");
                    pa = user.next();
                } while (!(pa.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || pa.equalsIgnoreCase("n")));

                System.out.println("\n");

                // display final results / report
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Computer Dice Results");
                System.out.println("---------------------");
                System.out.println("You played " + (wins + ties + loses) + " rounds");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Rounds won\t:" + wins);
                System.out.println("Rounds lost\t:" + loses);
                System.out.println("---------------------");
                System.out.println();
            }
        } while (pa.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
        user.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your first `do` statement does not have a corresponding `while` statement at the end. Also you have an extra `}`

Comment: OHHHH I completely disregarded the first do statement at the beginning of my code. Wow can I not think today or what haha Thank you!